# C# string replacement question

Tags: c#, string

Quick question.  I have a listbox being populated from a directory listing.  Each file contains its name and ~#####.  I'm trying to read it all into a string and replace the ~#### with nothing.  The #### could be digits from length 1-6 and could be anything from 0-9.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
string listItem = (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("~*",""));
```

Example:

```
Here223~123  --->  Here
Here224~2321 ----> Here
```

I can't replace any number because I need the numbers before the ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
string listItem = 
      listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 
           listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().IndexOf("~"));
```

Comment: Man, I mainly voted to get you from 9,990 to 10k. But you seem to have hit the cap for today already. :-)

Comment: @Tomalak, I already made 232 pts today; it's hard to get an accepted answer when you need one =)

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
listItem.Split("~")[0]
```

This should give you the first string in an array of strings, that way you've lost the tilda and trailing string after that.

Answer (score 6):

`string listItem = Regex.Replace(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), "~[0-9]{1,6}", string.Empty);`

should do the trick (can't remember if you have to escape ~ though!)

Comment: i would love to do the regex, but i cant get it to compile.  it thinks there is a newline starting at the "

Comment: that's odd, Regex is normally pretty good with newlines ('\n's). Regex is also a great tool in your arsenal for problems like this, especially as they get more complex, as Split is not quite as specific.

Comment: @Mike, just a missing `"`; try it again

Comment: @Rubens thanks for the edit, hadn't noticed it'd munched my syntax!

Answer (score 4):

You may be better of using the Substring(int startIndex, int lenght) method:

```
string listItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.toString();
listItem = listitem.SubString(0, listItem.IndexOf("~"));
```

Answer (score 1):

the point is that string.replace does not do regular expressions

so either split on "~", or use regex